# How to import date (YYYY-MM-DD) data from a file?

Tags: import, date-and-time

I have a file with data in form `{date, value}`:
`2010-05-19 17` 
`2010-05-20 20` 
`2010-05-21 19` 
`...`
How would I import such data in form `{DateList, value}`?

Comment: Kudos for using the [ISO 8601](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/iso-time.html) standard date format. The Fred Flintstone Format (MM/DD/YY) should be banned! :-)

Comment: @stevenvh as should be yards, inches and non-ISO units in general (my favorite is psi).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Import[(* file *), "Table", "DateStringFormat" -> {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day"}]` seems to work...

---

As a test:

```
Export["test.dat",
       {{"2010-05-19", 17}, {"2010-05-20", 20}, {"2010-05-21", 19}},
       "FieldSeparators" -> " "];

Import["test.dat", "Table",
       "DateStringFormat" -> {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day"}]
{{{2010, 5, 19}, 17}, {{2010, 5, 20}, 20}, {{2010, 5, 21}, 19}}
```

Comment: Beat me by a minute!

Comment: Can you fix up yours to explicitly show that it works on the sample data? Then I'll delete mine.

Comment: @J.M. It seems that no "-" is needed. Thanks.

Comment: @Szabolcs, Done.

Comment: @enedene: I wanted to show how to indicate delimiters explicitly, should you encounter a more peculiar date format. Replace the dashes accordingly in the code above.

Comment: @J.M. good point.