# import complete date string to mathematica

Tags: string-manipulation

Based on an example from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/933/how-to-import-date-yyyy-mm-dd-data-from-a-file) I try to parse dates from a table including the time, but it fails. This is the modified example:

```
Export["test.dat", {{"2010-05-19 22:23:43", 17}, {"2010-05-20 22:23:43", 20}, {"2010-05-21 22:23:43", 19}}, "FieldSeparators" -> " "];

Import["test.dat", "Table", "DateStringFormat" -> {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day", " ", "Hour", ":", "Minute", ":", "Second"}]
```

Does anyone understand why it doesn't work in analogy to the other case?

thanks

Comment: "DateStringFormat" seems to only return three elements (Y,M,D ) even if (Y,M,D H:M:S) are specified and apparently recognised.

Answer (score 7):

A workaround:

```
imported = Import["test.dat", "Table"]
```

We get:

```
(* {{"2010-05-19 22:23:43", 17}, {"2010-05-20 22:23:43", 
    20}, {"2010-05-21 22:23:43", 19}} *)
```

You can then apply `DateList` to convert it to a date list:

```
MapAt[DateList, #, 1] & /@ imported

(* {{{2010, 5, 19, 22, 23, 43.}, 17}, {{2010, 5, 20, 22, 23, 43.}, 
    20}, {{2010, 5, 21, 22, 23, 43.}, 19}} *)
```

Comment: Even shorter: `MapAt[DateList, #, 1] & /@ imported`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard you're right, I'm going to correct it.